# How to bind value to hyperlink property?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

The next code is a part of a Grid View,i am trying to bind data to hyperlink control in the grid view.
The properties of the hyperlink is changing,it depends on the choose,so i need to make them dynamic and bind data to the when the user choose the option,this is the code:

```
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="Download" runat="server"   HeaderText='<%# Eval("choose") %>'
                    DataTextField='<%# Eval("choose") %>' DataNavigateUrlFields='<%# Eval("choose") %>'>


                </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

"choose" is a string on server side that gets the name of my column name in the data base that i want to display.

I got this error:

> 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name
>   'choose'.

Comment: What is the source of your GridView? Does your GridView source containing Choose Property?

Comment: Its a function on the server side,that populates the grid view from a sql data base.my db contains only one simple table with 2 columns.

Comment: So, it is DataTable, yes? It there Column with the name choose?

Comment: Yes its a Data Table,there are three columns total one named "ID" second named "News" and third named "Sports". There is no column with the name choose

Comment: So, what is Choose? The text inside Eval must be the name of the column in the DataTable. So, it is true that your 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name choose, yes?

Comment: maybe i didn't understood the 'Eval' class,i needed to insert a parameter that contains different string each time,so i can make it dynamic,so how can i do it differently? the column name is always changing depends on user choose,so each time i need to insert from different column.

Comment: I can't help you, because there is not exact question. :(  Could you explain your problem from the beginning. Your solution might be wrong. So, it would be nice, if you will explain the problem slowly.

Comment: ok,i have 10 buttons lets say,each time a user press some button,i need to go to my data base and take the column that have exact name like the button the user pressed,now,lets say user pressed "News",so im going to database fill the data table with the column named "News",and i show the data in the grid view as links,that's the idea,the problem is that i don't know how to change the hyper link properties like  'DataTextField=column name', i want the 'column name' to be be a variable that gets the needed string when button is pressed,when i pressed "News" ==> column name=News.

Comment: You could have three HyperLinks and make two of them invisible, and the other one visible after setting source of the GridView. No?

Comment: its a one way to go i guess,but i cant fined a way to access the Hyperlink or the Template fields on the server side.

Comment: You can use RowDataBound event of the GridView and find the control like that:
`protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink myHyperLink = e.Row.FindControl("myHyperLinkID") as HyperLink;
    }
}`

Comment: ok il try it,thanx,il post later.